# Getting a NameError in an If Else statement in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write an if/else statement in Python but I keep getting the NameError.

```
ld = 2
rd = 0
hd = 1
vhd = 1

if(rd>= 1):
    rt = (4*rd) + 2

elif(hd>=1 and rd==0):
    st = (4*hd + 2)

elif(ld>=1 and rd==0 and hd==0):
    lt = (4*ld + 2)

elif(ld>=1):
    lt = 4*ld

elif(hd>=1):
    st = hd

elif(vhd>=1):
    spt = vhd

else: 
    print('Error!')

print(spt)
```

It gives me this error but instead, I want it to print the number 4 based on the formula.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-4a8714f7f508> in <module>
----> 1 print(spt)

NameError: name 'spt' is not defined
```

Comment: You only defined spt inside the `if`. What value should it have if `vhd < 1`?

Comment: To `print` `spt` outside the if-else statement, you should define/initiate it out side of the expression. As the same level you do at the top like `ld`, `rd` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Define `spt` before it's called.

Answer (score 0):

based on your variable initialization, your second `elif` condition is getting called but you are printing `spt` variable here. you can print right into your conditions rather than assigning into variable.

Comment: Eventually I want to run print(lt, rt, st, spt). Can you show me how to add all of those in the if else?

Comment: What is the point of printing all the variables? You have lots of if-else-if to assign the values into variables. One way to initialize all the variables at the beginning with zero, but while printing you will not able to differentiate whether this is initialized zero or calculated zero. Another way to check if you have variable using locals() in python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare all missing variables on top. Here is corrected version:

```
ld = 2
rd = 0
hd = 1
vhd = 1
lt = 0
rt = 0
st = 0
spt = 0

if(rd>= 1):
    rt = (4*rd) + 2

elif(hd>=1 and rd==0):
    st = (4*hd + 2)

elif(ld>=1 and rd==0 and hd==0):
    lt = (4*ld + 2)

elif(ld>=1):
    lt = 4*ld

elif(hd>=1):
    st = hd

elif(vhd>=1):
    spt = vhd

else:
    print('Error!')

print(lt, rt, st, spt)
```